# magento cron job module not working

Tags: php, xml, magento, cron

I wanted to setup a cron job inside my module. I followed the instructions on Magento wiki - how_to_setup_a_cron_job, but my cron job is simply not executing.

**1) This is my config.xml (app/code/local/Phoenixsharp/Notify/etc/config.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <phoenixsharpnotifycron>
                <class>Phoenixsharp_Notify_Model</class>
            </phoenixsharpnotifycron>                         
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
         <jobs>
             <phoenixsharpnotifycron>
                <schedule>
                     <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                 <run>                    <model>phoenixsharpnotifycron/testcron::sendUpdates</model>
                 </run>
             </phoenixsharpnotifycron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab> </config>
```

**2) And this is my model class. (app/code/local/Phoenixsharp/Notify/Model/Testcron.php)**

```
 <?php //this is model class class
class Phoenixsharp_Notify_Model_Testcron{ 
    public function sendUpdates() {
        Mage::log("WORKS!");    } } ?>
```

Comment: Isn't the Magento Wiki offline? And this question has been already asked and answered. From the existing duplicate Q&A material it is not clear in what your question is different. If you could highlight a difference with your question and make clear about which detail you're concerned specifically, please outline. A general "not working" doesn't qualify as a useful Q&A question neither.

Comment: ya i got, its working.